# Join mysql with multiple queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have three different SQL tables I need to join:

1. table "internet" with columns `id|type|status`
2. table "type_list" with columns `id|type_name`
3. table "status_list" with columns `id|status_name`

I want to output text from the two other tables (type_list, status_list) but not values as numbers which currently I have in table "internet".

I also don't want to make lazy programming - PHP array to make ID's equal to something like

```
$type_list = array("1"=>"VDSL2","2"=>"ADSL"); 
$status_list = array("1"=>"Pending","2"=>"Active");
```

because the text is already in the tables, i just dont know how to join them and output the text as query combined together in one query.

Answer (score 0):

Use `JOIN`

```
SELECT i.id,  type_name, status_name
FROM internet i
LEFT OUTER JOIN type_list t ON t.id = i.type
LEFT OUTER JOIN status_list s ON s.id= i.status
```

Read the [MySQL doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) for more informations.

Answer (score 0):

Just write the select with the fields you want.

```
select internet.id,type_name,status_name from internet 
inner join type_list
on type_list.id=internet.id
inner join status_list
on status_list.id=internet.id
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you need a `LEFT JOIN`, like so:

```
SELECT i.id, t.type_name, s.status_name
FROM internet AS i
LEFT JOIN type_list AS t ON t.id = i.id
LEFT JOIN status_list AS s ON s.id= i.id
```

*From your question, it is unclear what field you would like to join the queries on. In the above example, the queries are joined on the `id` field.*

*Please also note that the `AS` is not actually necessary, I have just put it in there to make it clear what is going on*